# How to Edit the Order of Global Colors in Elementor?

Tags: css, options

I looked all over for a solution to changing the order of the global colors in Elementor, but didn't find one. People have asked how to do this both in Elementor's forum as well as reddit and a few other locations. Sadly, no solution.

Comment: Elementor and other 3rd party plugin/theme dev support is off topic and not in this stacks scope. You should ask via their official support routes or in their groups and communities.

Comment: This is related to WordPress - NOT OFF TOPIC. Your comment is the reason SO and related forums are becoming irrelevant. Either a question is in the wrong place, or a user gets flamed for asking a question that was answered a decade ago. For this particular question with answer I provided has already been upvoted by 2 people DUE TO RELEVANCE!!!! Very poor choice in closing this.

Comment: 3rd party plugin dev support is off-topic here and not in this stacks scope. You cannot ask questions here about how to modify Elementor, it is against the rules. If this question is not about Elementor then you can update your question and vote to re-open, or go to the meta stack, there is a process that can be followed.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've come up with:

This can be done from within the database. You will want to look for _elementor_page_settings inside the wp_postmeta table. The meta_value will be serialized data, so save a copy of the _elementor_page_settings data before making an edit.

In your data, say you have the following:

```
{{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 2";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:1;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 3";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:2;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 1";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:3;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 4";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}}
```

What you'd like to do is move the following to the top of the list:

```
i:2;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 1";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
```

What you will do is moving it as shown below:

```
{{i:2;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 1";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:0;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 2";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:1;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 3";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:3;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 4";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}}
```

If you add your new update as it is above, you will break the majority of your list because the index is in the following order: 2,0,1,3. You still need to update the index value to be 0,1,2,3:

Look for i:N, where N is your numbering from 0 to the last number in your list. After changing the index for all colors in your list, you will have the following:

```
{{i:0;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 1";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:1;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 2";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:2;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 3";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}
i:3;a:3:{s:3:"_id";s:7:"de51da3";s:5:"title";s:6:"Blue 4";s:5:"color";s:7:"#123456";}}
```

You may have 5, or you may have 50 colors in your global colors list. You'll have to update that value for all color records. And make sure to not change the name of your color or any other value here. All serialized data in this list has a character counter associated with it. Only change the names from within Elementor's editor as it will handle the serialized data changes for you.