# Elementor - Edit Global Colors Order

Tags: css, options

I'm trying to change the order of the Elementor global colors list.

This question was originally posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/399129/how-to-edit-the-order-of-global-colors-in-elementor), and while the instructions are thorough, I can't find the elementor_page_settings in the wp_postmeta table that is specified in that post.

Apparently, I don't have enough points to either add a comment to that post or pm the member who provided the answer, so not sure how to get past this.

Is there an alternative location where the page settings data is stored? I'm thinking possibly this may have changed (although the answer in the original post is fairly recent). Any help would be greatly appreciated - my original global color list is a bit of a mess and I want to add a clean theme of colors at the top...thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed Elementor and this was added to a default kit page. I would double check the table you are searching and make sure the meta_key is right.

[image]

Comment: Hey, many thx. I finally realized the problem - my version of elementor_page_settings is co-mingling fonts and colors - and in the result list view, only the font kw's are visible.  So, now I can see the color settings, but each record has a combination of color, font (and other settings). And...there are 48 records in the result set...TBH, this is an older site and I suspect I may have some data quality / corruption issues.

Comment: Mark, I keyed off your comment about a new install - 2 records to start and 1 rec added for each new color (or other global attrib) added. I'm guessing it's version control. TBH, while the original post had a clear explanation of how to modify the color array, I'm not clear on the structure when other attribs (e.g. font) are added to the record. I'm gonna leave things as-is on the old site and just clear out any mods I made to the new site - my global settings are std enough that I don't need to modify the sort order once I've entered a complete list.  Thx again!

Comment: I'm fairly sure you are right about it being a form of version control. 

Can always just toss the data through a function to unserialize it and make it easier to read.